# How to track answers to one's comments or answers or posts; When I am notified ?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Didn't we used to get notified when there was activity on a question or answer that we made a comment on?  If so I am no longer getting notifications on such activity, and I have no way to track what I've made comments on other than to try and remember where I made them.  some way to track your comments like your questions/answers would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will get notifications of activity that is directed at you, ie

- answers on your questions
- comments on your posts
- comments replying to you via @DForck42.

You can see comments you have made in your [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95710/dforck42?tab=activity).  You can separately view responses on your [responses page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95710/dforck42?tab=responses).

For the entire network, notifications are shown to you in the inbox area (click `StackExchange` in the upper left of any page).  A red number will appear to the left of that when you have a new notification.  You can view your [combined network inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/b9514e0d-a0b1-4812-8d9e-7ec387a23fdc?tab=inbox) and [combined network activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/b9514e0d-a0b1-4812-8d9e-7ec387a23fdc?tab=activity) via your stackexchange.com network profile.

Comment: i... never noticed that before.  thank you.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, notifications are shown if

1. You're the OP and someone makes a comment on your post
2. You make a comment on a post and the OP replies and you two are the *only* people conversing
3. You make a comment on a post and someone tags you with  @username

Do notifications not work for you in these cases?

You can also view all responses to you by visiting the `Responses` tab in your user profile.

Answer (score 2):

Din't you get any notifications on following comments?

- [@DForck42: yes, I'm using perfmon to track several others counters. BCHR loo...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5721998)
- [@DForck42: indeed! This "order" is bizarre enough to warrant at the ve...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5676755)
- [via java code - no ui...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552168)
- [@DForck42: See also http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5489563)
- [@DForck42: How would you make a given attribute mandatory?  In a conventional de...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5516950)
- ["Everything" isn't actually that much. The additional overhead is ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5521680)
- [@DForck42, @JNK - Might be more useful if you provided a create script that you ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5490601)
- [@DForck42: I incline to gbn's solution with applocks, but there are some pit...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5407817)
- [@DForck42 - UDFs don't always incur execution prior to filtering, just in th...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5262967)
- [@DForck42: you probably can't get it through the crippled OLE DB provider si...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4996469)
- [Thanks for the idea @DForck42, I tried playing with Gridlines but the problem co...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974118)
- [@DForck42: The upvote will be sufficient. :-)...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4619369)
- [@DForck42 I did see that :-) What I meant was that sometimes it is a good idea t...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4569886)
- [@DForck42 I half agree. Of course, a design could be inefficient and cause ineff...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4569886)
- [@DForck42 Does it timeout at the same point each time? ie...30 seconds? What is ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4539765)
- [@DForck42: That's correct, but each select is complex and there are many sel...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4125112)
- [@DForck42, no it's not.  That's the structure I already have.  I wanted ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3972386)
- [@DForck I think I understand what you're saying, but I don't think cachi...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067537)
- [@DForck This isn't a data issue, it's a display issue. I don't need ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3920226)
- [@DForck42 - Good point.  @jenny - you should consider bouncing back this "b...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3754077)
- [@DForck: do you mean doing that in the client query, so that each query to this ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3716546)
- [@DForck42 - I read that earlier but couldn't see an explanation in there. Di...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3636315)

Comment: i don't believe so, at least not hte first few.  the rest are too old for me to really remember.